# Java equivalent of Python's struct.pack?

Tags: java, struct, pack

Is there any function equivalent to Python's `struct.pack` in Java that allows me to pack and unpack values like this?

```
pump_on = struct.pack("IIHHI", 0, 0, 21, 96, 512)
```

Comment: Is there an accepted answer for this question?

Comment: It's not the exact equivalent of Python's pack but maybe it helps you anyway: https://github.com/marc-christian-schulze/structs4java

Answer (score 9):

I think what you may be after is a [ByteBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html):

```
ByteBuffer pump_on_buf = ...
pump_on_buf.putInt(0);
pump_on_buf.putInt(0);
pump_on_buf.putShort(21);
pump_on_buf.putShort(96);
pump_on_buf.putInt(512);
byte[] pump_on = pump_on_buf.array();
```

Comment: ByteBuffer doesn't allow you to write Strings, and the contractor requires a buffer size limitation - you need to pre-decide how long your input would be.

Comment: @Yonatan, it does allow you to write strings: `buf.put(s.getBytes())`.  `ByteBuffer` requires you to specify the capacity when initially allocating the buffer.  Are you saying this is a good thing or a bad thing?

Comment: @SimonC ByteBuffer does allow you two write strings in the manner you have shown. However, s.getBytes() will return a UTF-8 encoded byte array from the string (still variable length). It will not have a trailing zero. Beyond that buf.put() uses the current position in the ByteBuffer. This may not be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream data = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream(data);
stream.writeUTF(name);
stream.writeUTF(password);
final byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray(); // there you go
```

Later, you can read that data:

```
final DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(
  new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)
);
final String user = stream.readUTF();
final String password = stream.readUTF();
```

Comment: DataOutputStream is good for java primitives only. ObjectOutputStream (which also implements DataOutput interface) gives you ability to write primitives and serializable objects.

Comment: in this code example it should be `data.toByteArray()` there is no `toByteArray` on DataOutputStream but instead is available on the ByteArrayOutputStream

Answer (score 4):

I started development of project which is very close to Python Struct: [java-binary-block-parser](https://github.com/raydac/java-binary-block-parser)
in JBBP it will look like

```
JBBPOut.BeginBin().Int(0,0).Short(21,96).Int(512).End().toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Closest feature in core Java is [Serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/). It converts object into byte sequence and back.

Comment: CAn't believe you. Even as I dislike Java, there should be something closer to being able to do things like this than serialization: Serialization gives you no control on which actual bytes are being created - it just allows you to recreate the same object with those bytes.

Comment: By default it gives you no control, but you can always customize it. Hint: search for readObject/writeObject on the page I gave you a link to. If that is not enough, check out http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html